# weird transpose behavior with Sparkit-Learn

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I'm using Sparkit-Learn's [SparkCountVectorizer](https://github.com/lensacom/sparkit-learn#sparkcountvectorizer) and [SparkTfidfVectorizer](https://github.com/lensacom/sparkit-learn#sparktfidftransformer) to convert a bunch of documents into a TFIDF matrix.

I get to create the TFIDF matrix and it has the correct dimensions (496,861 documents by 189,398 distinct tokens):

```py
>>> tfidf
<class 'splearn.rdd.SparseRDD'> from PythonRDD[20] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48
>>> tfidf.shape
(496861, 189398)
```

Slicing a single vector returns the correct output (1 document by 189,398 distinct tokens):

```py
>>> tfidf.flatMap(lambda x: x).take(1)
[<1x189398 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 49 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

Now I want to get the transpose of each document (i.e., a vector of dimensions 189,398 by 1):

```py
>>> tfidf.flatMap(lambda x: x.T).take(1)
```

But this is what I get instead:

```
[<1x7764 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 77 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

So, instead of a 189389x1 vector I get a 1x7764 vector. I understand the 7764: when I read the data I `.repartition()` it in 64 pieces and, as it turns out, 496861 (the number of documents) divided by 64 is 7763.4. What I do not understand is why Sparkit-Learn iterates by flat rows in one case (`lambda x: x`) and by partitions in the other case (`lambda x: x.T`). I'm utterly confused.

In case it matters, my end goal is to filter the TFIDF matrix so that I get only vectors with nonzero values in certain columns (i.e., only documents that contain certain words) and indexing the untransposed 1x189389 vector doesn't work (doesn't matter how many `[0]`s I put after the `x` I always get back the same 1x189389 vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You transpose a wrong thing. `splearn.rdd.SparseRDD` stores blocks of data, so you transpose blocks not individual vectors. If block has 7764 row and 18938 columns, then transposed one has 18938 rows and 7764 columns which will be iterated row by row when flattened.

What you need is:

```py
(tfidf
    # Iterate over each block and yield the rows
    # block-size x 18938 -> 1 x 18938
    .flatMap(lambda x: x) 
    # Take each row and transpose it
    # 1 x 18938 -> 1 x 18938
    .map(lambda x: x.T))
```

or

```py
(tfidf
    # Iterate over each row in block (generator expression) 
    # and transpose it block-size x 18938 -> block-size x 18938 x 1
    #
    # and then flatten (with flatMap) yielding rows 18938 x 1
    .flatMap(lambda xs: (x.T for x in xs)))
```

**Note**: I am not really familiar with Sparkit-learn so there can be some more elegant solution out there.